# How to achieve multiple pages?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have made this report in Jaspersoft Studio which needs to be printed 3 times, but with another title. The other information on the report is the same.

I have no idea how to achieve this, but I came up with an unnested SQL array first:

```
case when a.unnest = '1' then 'Title 1'
when a.unnest = '2' then 'Title 2'
when a.unnest = '3' then 'Title 3'
end as title_copy

FROM table_name
join (SELECT unnest(array['1', '2', '3'])) a on true
WHERE table_name.service_id  = '123456679'
```

Now I need to make something like a while loop based on 'title_copy' but how can this be achieved within Jaspersoft Studio?

If someone have any tips or any other suggestion to achieve 3 (same) pages in Jaspersoft Studio, I would love to hear it.

Comment: You can use subreport at group header/footer

Comment: Thanks Alex, I didn't searched good; 'the iReport multiple copies of same report with different label ' thread solved it for me.

Comment: Great. You are welcome :)